# How to handle repeated entries in the SQLite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

No experience in database design. I have a following situation:
A table with 5 entries.

```
<DeviceIdentificationstr, data1, data2, data3.... data 5>
```

A table can have more than one device information.
I have designed something like this:

```
create table mytable (
  sNo integer PRIMARY KEY,
  DeviceIdentificationStr TEXT,
  data1 integer,
  data2 TEXT, ....)
```

Consider the following Scenario:

```
Record 1:    1, "Device1", "data1",  20, "data2", "data3"....
Record 2:    2, "Device2", "data1",  120, "data2", "data3"....
Record 3:    3, "Device2", "data1",  220, "data2", "data3"....
Record 4:    4, "Device1", "data1",  230, "data2", "data3"....
```

Here `Device1` and `Device2` are repeated all the time.

Are there any alternative way to design a table? Or is this the only way to go?

Also, i need to query something like: :Get  all records of "Device1".

Comment: What is the problem? If records 1 and 3 both have `Device1` as the value of  `DeviceIdentificationStr` then of course this value is repeated. Only if there is more to a device than an identification string, you could move the device information to a separate table.

Comment: What have you tried to answer your 'get all records of "Device1"' question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform so called normalization: create another table `devices`:

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
    device_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    DeviceIdentificationStr TEXT,
    DeviceMemory INTEGER,
    -- add more fields that describe device properties...
);
```

Change first table to be:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    sNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id INTEGER,
    data1 integer,
    data2 TEXT,
    ...
)
```

Now, you can use joins to get desired information, like this:

```
SELECT m.*,
    d.DeviceMemory,
    ...
FROM mytable m
    JOIN devices d USING (device_id)
WHERE d.DeviceIdentificationStr = 'mydevice'
```

Comment: How do you know that `device` has more than `DeviceIdentificationStr`? Why normalize a single value?

Comment: Practice. There is no way that device has only name - it must have something more to it

Answer (score -1):

First you have to check if the device exists in the table using [SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) statement, then update that particular row using [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement.